# how to reset sound source in PowerAudio?

Tags: javascript, audio, visualization

I'm using the PowerAudio audio visualizer (https://7ph.github.io/poweraudio/)

How do I change the audio source once it's initialized with:

```
this.myVisualizer = new PowerAudio.Viz({
                    container: '#visualization',
                    source: this.snd,
                });
```

Setting this.myVisualizer.source = newSource doesn't work (the visualization goes empty), and re-creating a new PowerAudio.Viz() each time makes the vizualization jitter after a few goes (so it mustn't be releasing some resources or something)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow 3 steps

- you can calling pause method
- then palyback time 0 (it's a beginning time)
- and finally clear the source url

I hope it can solve

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nayem37, I tried this but no luck :( Here's what I tried:
                this.myVisualizer.options.source.pause();
                this.myVisualizer.options.source.currentTime = 0;
                this.myVisualizer.options.source.src = undefined;
                this.myVisualizer.options.source = this.snd;